# Show that $n^2<n!$ for all $n\geq 4$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, inequality, induction, factorial

Show that $n^2<n!$ for all $n\geq 4$

What I did was

Base case:

$4^2<4!\iff16<24$

Inductive hypothesis:

Being that for a $n\leq k$, the equation remains true, we prove for $k+1$

$$\begin{align*}k^2+(k+1)^2&<(k+1)!\\
\iff k^2+(k+1)^2&<(k+1)*k!\end{align*}$$

as $k!>k^2$, summing $(k+1)^2$ will be also less than multiplying by $k+1$.

However, I don't know if this is correct or complete at all. Am I missing anything?

Comment: You want to show $(k+1)^2<(k+1)!$ and **not** $k^2+(k+1)^2<(k+1)!.$

Comment: oh, ok. How do I know if I have to sum or substitute?

Comment: Since you have to show for $n=k+1,$ so put $n=k+1.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You assume $k^2 <k!$ and want to show result is true for $n=k+1.$ That is you want to show $(k+1)^2<(k+1)!.$

Consider $$\begin{align*}(k+1)!&=(k+1)k!\\
&>(k+1)k^2\qquad \text{(induction hypothesis)}\\
&>(k+1)(k+1)\qquad \text{(since } k^2>k+1)\\
&=(k+1)^2.\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 2):

This is a great start! From the first line of your chain of inequalities, it looks like you're trying to prove $k^2 + (k + 1)^2 < (k + 1)!$, which is false, instead of $(k + 1)^2 < (k + 1)!$, and your last step isn't very clear (why is adding $(k + 1)^2$ less than multiplying by $k + 1$?). The right way to set up this proof is to assume that $k^2 < k!$ is true, and try to prove that $(k + 1)^2 < (k + 1)!$.

So you can set up a chain of inequalities that you're trying to prove:
\begin{align}
(k + 1)! & = (k + 1) \cdot k! \\
& \vdots \\
& > (k + 1)^2
\end{align}

Can you fill in the details of the proof? The first step should be applying the inductive hypothesis that $k! > k^2$.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to use the induction? If you consider 
$$
\frac{n!}{n^2} \geq \frac{(n-1)!}{n} \geq \frac{(\frac{n}{2})^{\frac{n}{2}}}{n} = \frac{n^{\frac{n}{2}-1}}{2^{\frac{n}{2}}} \geq 1 \ \text{for} \ n \geq 4
$$

Comment: I do have to use induction, but thanks!

Comment: @Duarte Arribas Even using induction, you can use the first step implicit in this answer and divide each side by $n$. Then you can prove that $n<(n-1)!$ inductively.